# Can Workflow Module be "non-linear"

Tags: 8, nodes, workflows

I have two potential workflows in mind for website content:

**"Regular" Content**

1. Write Article (Draft)
2. Content/Style Review
3. Publish Content

**"Sensitive" Content**

1. Write Article (Draft)
2. Compliance review
3. Content/Style Review
4. Publish Content

I'm trying to come with some way to direct the content to one of the two workflows.

In my system, if something has a certain taxonomy, it needs to go into the "sensitive" queue. If not, It can go through the normal queue.

It SEEMS like the default workflow is just set up to go A>B>C and I don't see where I can configure any logic. Thoughts?

Great Tutorial Here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mh9qQdq4sp8